# How to Display Tab Delimited Text File Into DataGridView including the Headers?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have this MS Access table with the following structure:

[image]

I extracted the data into a tab delimited text file with no text qualifier:

[image]

I found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639699/oledb-selecting-multiple-csvs-with-first-row-as-field-names-in-c-sharp) article but it doesn't work for tab delimited file.
I don't know how to display this data into DataGridView including the headers. Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but the easiest path I would guess would be reading the file into a DataTable (the FileHelpers library could help if needed) and then binding your DataGridView to that DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = CsvFileToDatatable(@"c:\a.csv",true);

public DataTable CsvFileToDatatable(string path, bool IsFirstRowHeader)//here Path is root of file and IsFirstRowHeader is header is there or not
        {
            string header = "No";
            string sql = string.Empty;
            DataTable dataTable = null;
            string pathOnly = string.Empty;
            string fileName = string.Empty;

            try
            {

                pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

                sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

                if (IsFirstRowHeader)
                {
                    header = "Yes";
                }

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                        @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                        ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                        {
                            dataTable = new DataTable();
                            dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                            adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {

            }

            return dataTable;

        }
```